# Genymotion suddenly stops with Segmentation fault (Core Dumped)

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox

I am running Arch Linux (`4.6.3-1-ARCH`) with GNOME 3.20 . I installed genymotion from the AUR : https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/genymotion/ , Whenever I launch the application , After 2-3 minutes, It suddenly closes.

```
[severus@Tux genymotion]$ genymotion
Logging activities to file: /home/severus/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[severus@Tux genymotion]$
```

Here is the log file from .Genymobile/genymotion.log

```
Jun 28 06:45:08 [Genymotion] [Debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
Jun 28 06:45:08 [Genymotion] [Debug] "Local socket created at path : /tmp/907f397a1f5a71abaaa526042f58a1b0"
Jun 28 06:45:08 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
Jun 28 06:45:08 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion "2.7.1"
Jun 28 06:45:08 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("/usr/bin/genymotion")
Jun 28 06:45:08 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] [HttpRequest::exec] Request timeout (code: 0 ) : "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Error] Network error while retrieving JSON content:  0
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Error] [getGenymotionLastVersion] Bad request: "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to get last Genymotion version number from server:  0
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Warning] QIODevice::read: device not open
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Error] Invalid json received: "illegal value"
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Status: 0
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Content: ""
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Reply error: "Operation canceled" ( 5 )
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] last error msg: "Invalid reply from server"
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel"
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "7fdafbbf"
Jun 28 06:45:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage"
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 3888
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] Checking "vboxnet0" interface status (  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.1" )  )
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" Interface is down
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] Deleting "vboxnet0" host-only interface
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "remove", "vboxnet0") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Interface "vboxnet0" created with success
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:13 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "remove", "--ifname", "vboxnet0") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "add", "--ifname", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.100", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0", "--lowerip", "192.168.56.101", "--upperip", "192.168.56.254", "--enable") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] DHCP server created with success
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" host-only interface is ready to use
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.22_OSEr108108"
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] VMX/SVM CPU availability: true
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.22_OSEr108108"
Jun 28 06:45:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "vms") returns 0
Jun 28 06:45:17 [Genymotion] [Debug] Logged on Hub
Jun 28 06:45:17 [Genymotion] [Debug] Pending calls: 0
Jun 28 06:45:17 [Genymotion] [Debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" ) 
Jun 28 06:45:19 [Genymotion] [Debug] [tokenError] "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN"
Jun 28 06:45:21 [Genymotion] [Debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/getall" ) 
Jun 28 06:45:35 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion template count: 97
Jun 28 06:45:35 [Genymotion] [Debug] template list retrieved:  97
Jun 28 06:46:08 [Genymotion] [Debug] Searching virtual device with same name
Jun 28 06:46:09 [Genymotion] [Debug] Launching download
Jun 28 06:46:09 [Genymotion] [Debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/ec8546af-7300-4f35-a88b-559f19672ff8/getova" ) 
Jun 28 06:46:09 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jun 28 06:46:10 [Genymotion] [Debug] Start timer
Jul 1 05:24:45 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:24:45 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:24:45 [Genymotion] [Debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
Jul 1 05:24:45 [Genymotion] [Debug] "Local socket created at path : /tmp/907f397a1f5a71abaaa526042f58a1b0"
Jul 1 05:24:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
Jul 1 05:24:45 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion "2.7.1"
Jul 1 05:24:45 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("genymotion")
Jul 1 05:24:45 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Jul 1 05:24:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
Jul 1 05:24:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] [getGenymotionLastVersion] New version ( "2.7.2" ) available here: "https://www.genymotion.com/download/"
Jul 1 05:24:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] Last version of Genymotion is  "2.7.2"
Jul 1 05:24:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
Jul 1 05:24:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
Jul 1 05:24:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel"
Jul 1 05:24:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "7fdafbbf"
Jul 1 05:24:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage"
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Logged on Hub
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Pending calls: 0
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" ) 
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/stats/report/genymotion/"
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [tokenError] "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN"
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Stats sent
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 3888
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:47 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] Checking "vboxnet0" interface status (  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.1" )  )
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" Interface is down
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] Deleting "vboxnet0" host-only interface
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "remove", "vboxnet0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Interface "vboxnet0" created with success
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "remove", "--ifname", "vboxnet0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "add", "--ifname", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.100", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0", "--lowerip", "192.168.56.101", "--upperip", "192.168.56.254", "--enable") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] DHCP server created with success
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" host-only interface is ready to use
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.22_OSEr108108"
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VMX/SVM CPU availability: true
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.22_OSEr108108"
Jul 1 05:24:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "vms") returns 0
Jul 1 05:24:55 [Genymotion] [Debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/getall" ) 
Jul 1 05:24:58 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion template count: 97
Jul 1 05:24:58 [Genymotion] [Debug] template list retrieved:  97
Jul 1 05:25:10 [Genymotion] [Debug] Searching virtual device with same name
Jul 1 05:25:11 [Genymotion] [Debug] Launching download
Jul 1 05:25:11 [Genymotion] [Debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/d4e07f01-26ac-4fb1-ab30-ba6ca71a1fd2/getova" ) 
Jul 1 05:25:11 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:25:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] Start timer
Jul 1 05:25:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] Remote file size: 176926720 , current local file size: 0
Jul 1 05:25:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] Starting new download
Jul 1 05:25:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] Downloading file  "http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/4.3/ova/genymotion_vbox86p_4.3_160609_180435.ova"
Jul 1 05:25:12 [Genymotion] [Debug] Start timer
Jul 1 05:29:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:29:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:29:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
Jul 1 05:29:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] "Local socket created at path : /tmp/907f397a1f5a71abaaa526042f58a1b0"
Jul 1 05:29:02 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
Jul 1 05:29:02 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion "2.7.1"
Jul 1 05:29:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("genymotion")
Jul 1 05:29:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [getGenymotionLastVersion] New version ( "2.7.2" ) available here: "https://www.genymotion.com/download/"
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] Last version of Genymotion is  "2.7.2"
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel"
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "7fdafbbf"
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage"
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] Logged on Hub
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] Pending calls: 0
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" ) 
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 3888
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] Checking "vboxnet0" interface status (  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.1" )  )
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" Interface is down
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] Deleting "vboxnet0" host-only interface
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "remove", "vboxnet0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
Jul 1 05:29:03 [Genymotion] [Debug] [tokenError] "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN"
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Interface "vboxnet0" created with success
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "remove", "--ifname", "vboxnet0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "add", "--ifname", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.100", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0", "--lowerip", "192.168.56.101", "--upperip", "192.168.56.254", "--enable") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] DHCP server created with success
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" host-only interface is ready to use
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.22_OSEr108108"
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VMX/SVM CPU availability: true
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.22_OSEr108108"
Jul 1 05:29:04 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "vms") returns 0
Jul 1 05:29:06 [Genymotion] [Debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/getall" ) 
Jul 1 05:29:08 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion template count: 97
Jul 1 05:29:08 [Genymotion] [Debug] template list retrieved:  97
Jul 1 05:29:15 [Genymotion] [Debug] Searching virtual device with same name
Jul 1 05:29:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Launching download
Jul 1 05:29:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/ec8546af-7300-4f35-a88b-559f19672ff8/getova" ) 
Jul 1 05:29:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:29:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Start timer
Jul 1 05:29:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Remote file size: 176926720 , current local file size: 2229780
Jul 1 05:29:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Starting new download
Jul 1 05:29:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Downloading file  "http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/4.3/ova/genymotion_vbox86p_4.3_160609_180435.ova"
Jul 1 05:29:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Start timer
Jul 1 05:30:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:30:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:30:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
Jul 1 05:30:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] "Local socket created at path : /tmp/907f397a1f5a71abaaa526042f58a1b0"
Jul 1 05:30:46 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
Jul 1 05:30:46 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion "2.7.1"
Jul 1 05:30:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("genymotion")
Jul 1 05:30:46 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [getGenymotionLastVersion] New version ( "2.7.2" ) available here: "https://www.genymotion.com/download/"
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Last version of Genymotion is  "2.7.2"
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel"
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "7fdafbbf"
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage"
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Logged on Hub
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] Pending calls: 0
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" ) 
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 3888
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] Checking "vboxnet0" interface status (  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.1" )  )
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" Interface is down
Jul 1 05:30:47 [Genymotion] [Debug] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] Deleting "vboxnet0" host-only interface
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "remove", "vboxnet0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Interface "vboxnet0" created with success
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "remove", "--ifname", "vboxnet0") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "add", "--ifname", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.100", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0", "--lowerip", "192.168.56.101", "--upperip", "192.168.56.254", "--enable") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] DHCP server created with success
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" host-only interface is ready to use
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.22_OSEr108108"
Jul 1 05:30:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VMX/SVM CPU availability: true
Jul 1 05:30:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VM engine version: "5.0.22_OSEr108108"
Jul 1 05:30:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "vms") returns 0
Jul 1 05:30:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] [tokenError] "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN"
Jul 1 05:30:54 [Genymotion] [Debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/getall" ) 
Jul 1 05:30:55 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion template count: 97
Jul 1 05:30:55 [Genymotion] [Debug] template list retrieved:  97
Jul 1 05:31:14 [Genymotion] [Debug] Searching virtual device with same name
Jul 1 05:31:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Launching download
Jul 1 05:31:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/ec8546af-7300-4f35-a88b-559f19672ff8/getova" ) 
Jul 1 05:31:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Jul 1 05:31:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Start timer
Jul 1 05:31:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Remote file size: 176926720 , current local file size: 2837366
Jul 1 05:31:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Starting new download
Jul 1 05:31:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Downloading file  "http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/4.3/ova/genymotion_vbox86p_4.3_160609_180435.ova"
Jul 1 05:31:16 [Genymotion] [Debug] Start timer
```

Does anyone know why this is happening ? Does anyone have similar problems ?

Comment: If you think this Post deserves a Downvote, please leave a comment why do you think so. I will try to improve it . And also it would help me for my future posts.

Comment: Anyone have the fix for this problem???

Comment: Is this error from your debug log relevant? "_HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN_"

Comment: Also, it may be useful to run it under strace, or generate a core file, or even run it inside gdb.  All those will provide a good deal of extra info.  The normal logfile may not have been flushed before the segfault and may be misleading.